# jqGrid: change editoptions in colModel between adding rows - NOT load editoptions from URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

**Summary:**

I am trying to change the editoptions column property on a **per-cell basis**.

**Please Note**, unlike everyone else on the internet with a similar question :), I am not loading grid data using jqgrid's built in functionality to fetch data from a URL.

**Background:**

We are using jqGrid to display between 1 or 2 dozen rows with roughly 6-8 columns in a grid.  Most cells in the grid are set up to use edittype:"select" and to display a drop-down, an example of which is below:

```
{name:'someColumn', index:'someIndex', key: true, width:100, align:"center", editable: true, edittype:"select",formatter:'select'},
```

ALL the row data comes in a big block from an AJAX call and we iterate over that data, using the 'addRowData' command, to put new rows into the grid.

```
grid.jqGrid('addRowData', undefined, oSelectedData);
```

In the past, we used to include an 'editoptions' property in the colModel, because a given column was supposed to have the same 'select' options for every row.  Now however, we are sending some extra data in the AJAX call that indicates which 'select' options that cell is supposed to have.  Therefore, we are trying to change the colModel's 'editoptions' for most of the columns every time a new row is added.  We attempt this using a 'setColProp' command that looks like this

```
grid.jqGrid('setColProp', columnName, {editoptions:{value:columnEditOptions}});
```

**Problem:**
The problem is that programmatically setting the column editoptions only seems to work for the first row in the grid.  I have confirmed that even though 'setColProp' is later called with different values for `columnEditOptions`, all of the 'select' drop-downs in all of the rows that are added later share the same options as the one from the first row.

**Is it possible to change the select options in each row using some method internal to jqGrid?**
To my knowledge, we are not using anything like row- or cell-based edit mode at all.

I'm using jqGrid 4.4.3

Comment: It's unclear **which editing mode you use** (inline editing, cell editing or form editing). It would be good if you create the demo which demonstrates what you do. I suppose that you just try to use jqGrid in the wrong way. For example filling the grid with respect of calling `addRowData` in the loop is the worst way to fill the grid, which I know (and the slowest one). One should use `data` parameter instead. You write that you loads all information about all selects. In which form you have the information? The usage of `key: true` for the column having `formatter: "select"` looks suspected.

Comment: The usage of retro version 4.4.3 is another problem. It's almost 4 years old. It's like trying to repair 40 year old car. I recommend to use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.13.5 instead. It has many callbacks, which allows you to customize select dynamically.